# ImproperlyConfigured urls.py in Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following error and I can't figure out what to change in my urls.py to fix this:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'MLtest.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Here's what my urls.py looks like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from MLT import views
import debug_toolbar

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.thankYou),
    path(r'^__debug__', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

def thankYou(request):
    text = _("this is some random text")
    return render(request, 'thank_you.html', {'text': text})
```

Comment: Change `r'^__debug__'` to `'__debug__/'`

Comment: I still get the error without the regex or even if I take out that entire path with the debug_toolbar

Comment: Show us views.py. A circular dependency can also cause this.

Comment: Added to question. See above.

Comment: You should show your folder structure, starting from the root project folder (where `manage.py` is located) down to the where urls.py and views.py are located.

Answer (score 2):

You mustn't use regex with path() function.Your last url `path(r'^__debug__', include(debug_toolbar.urls))` contains regex expression. You can see url definitions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: In fact, if I delete that whole path, I still get the error

Comment: Have you another url file?

Comment: Ok, have you `ROOT_URLCON`F definiton in your `settings.py` file?

Comment: Are your views and urls  files in different directory? Because you used `from MLT import views` for import views. but you defined `MLtest.urls` for urls

Comment: yes, they are in different directories. That makes a difference?

Comment: Ok. I just tried making a second urls.py in the same directory as my views.py and then adding `path('', include('MLT.urls')),` to MLtest\urls.py and the problem persists!

Comment: Strange. I deleted my urls.py and recreated it without all of the debug_toolbar stuff and the error went away...

Comment: It is very strange. Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: Using Version 3.0.3

Comment: In the documentation,`path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))`  added to urlpatterns if debug is True in settings.Could you try it like [here](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Answer (score 2):

correct your url as below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.thankYou),
    path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
]
```

Comment: i think you dont have any urls in 'MLtest.urls'

Comment: you should add urls there also, then you can get away from the error

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The urls.py file that I put in my question is the MLtest.urls file